# Using ICSx5 with a local file

Tags: calendar

The page at https://icsx5.bitfire.at/ says:  ICSx⁵ is an Android app to subscribe to remote (“Webcal”) or **local iCalendar files**  (my emphasis). But I don't understand how to add a file from the local storage of my Android phone to icsx5.
The app asks for a URL.  The path to my file is:

```
/Interner Speicher/Documents/calendar.ics
```

So how do I translate this into a URL?  Guesses so far:

```
file://Interner Speicher/Documents/calendar.ics
```

gives a complaint about an illegal character (the white space).

```
file://Interner%20Speicher/Documents/calendar.ics
file://Documents/calendar.ics
```

each throw the error "URI has an authority component".

```
file:///Interner%20Speicher/Documents/calendar.ics
file:/Interner%20Speicher/Documents/calendar.ics
file:///Documents/calendar.ics
file:/Documents/calendar.ics
```

each throw the error "file not found".

What else could I reasonably try?

(I first tried posting this question in the icsx5-support forum at https://forums.bitfire.at/category/5/icsdroid but that website seems to be broken in my browser -- I can't select a category for my question, and of course I can't submit the question without selecting a category.  If anyone else could post there, that would be greatly appreciated.)

Comment: You make one big mistake: you use Windows for looking at the directories if your phone. The problem is that Windows accesses the phone via MTP protocol and MTP does not show you the real file system. Therefore any path you see via MTP is non-existent on the phone. Use an Android file manager app instead or from a PC ADB for seeing the real file path.

Comment: No, I don't even have Windows. I'm using the (Samsung?) "My Files" app that came with the phone.

Comment: Ok, but no matter the used app also uses the media database (that is also used by MTP) to display the files and thus does not display the real path. I assume your device is running Android 10+? Use a different file manager app that displays the real path or change the display setting of the used app to display real paths.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I believe I managed to figure out the true path with a separate app, as you suggested. Using one or three "/" I now get a "permission denied" error. Seems I can give the app permission to read "media files" only. Guess that's a different question ...